# Windows 7 boot error

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers

I am running windows 7 professional, everything was working fine until I installed a software driver clearner suggested by nvidia customer service and I  cleaned only nvidia graphic driver installation since then my windows does not work at all.

I can access everything from startup repair, did lots of time repair but nothing happened. System restore does not work it says c: drive is not available, its 100% there and I can access every file from command prompt.

Almost two days passed and I applied every solution discussed on several forums, now only thing left is either install fresh windows (Which i really don't want to do) or update windows (which windows does not let me to do, it says I have to update it from windows)

My question is there any way to update (not fresh/custom installation) windows from command prompt?

P.s: Safe mode, safe mode command nothing works except startup repair option. I ran sfc /scannow no problem found. I also removed all attached hardwares.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried the repairinstallation with the windows dvd? I can´t read it out of your description. What do you mean by "I can access everything from startup repair, did lots of time repair but nothing happened."

Comment: thats what I am doing right now. I am trying to repair windows from the dvd but i haven't got luck. I tried to upgrade windows but it says i should run it from windows (not from windows setup)

Answer (score 1):

I would try Safe Mode again.

You said you ran `SFC.exe`, this is not the correct tool for the job,  FYI it stands for "System File Checker". It is only designed to fix/repair corrupt Windows system files, not third party drivers.

You need to uninstall and remove the Nvidia drivers and reinstall the previously working ones.

Go in to `Computer Management` (Click the `Start Orb`, right click `Computer`, click `Manage`).

Expand "Display Apdaters" and double click on the Nvidia card.

Next, go to the `Driver` Tab and see if you have the `Roll Back` option.

[image]

If you do, this should do the job great - if it doesn't, then click `Driver Details` and make a note of the locations of the Nvidia specific files (basically as you click on it, make sure Nvidia is listed and not Microsoft as you do not want to delete the generic graphic driver files).

Next, click "Uninstall" and check the option so that you actually delete the files - then double check against the above list to make sure they have been deleted.

Now, reboot and make sure the machine is working, and then simply reinstall the correct version of the drivers.

If this does not work for you, please write in comments how far you went and what problems you came up against and I will try to help you further.

Comment: i wish if safe mode works for me, like I said in my question I can't run windows in safe mode or even safemode command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a chkdsk from the command prompt.

chkdsk /r C:

I assume you booted from DVD to use system restore?

Comment: I did that, it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to restore my computer. Long time ago I created a dvd when I installed fresh copy of windows that worked for me. Somehow, system restore was not recognizing my backup drive where windows was storing daily backup images but when I booted from the rescue dvd it worked for me.

So far I am extremely very happy because it saved my months work!!

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How to do a Manual Windows SYSTEM RESTORE

This is known to work for XP, I have not tried it on W7, the registry structure is the same so it should work

A. Connect your non-bootable hard drive to another computer, as a secondary drive or use a usb adapter or enclsure and boot into windows. If you can see your data on the drive, back it up Now, then follow the rest of these instructions.

B. Open Windows Explorer.  Click on Tools|Folder Options|View.  Check the box beside "Show hidden files and folders".  Apply your change.

***NOTE***  D: may not represent the hard drive you connected to your PC, it may be E: or F: or G:, it all depends on how many other drives (including cd/dvd) you have in your PC, So subtitute the appropriate drive letter in the instructions below.

C. Navigate to the D:\System Volume Information folder.
You will see a folder named something like _restore{.........}  the dots represent an alpha-numeric sequence.
In this folder you will see folders named RP0....RPnn.  Find the one with the highest number. 
These are your System Restore points.  In the highest numbered folder you will see a folder named snapshot.  In this folder are registry hive files which you need to recover your system:

_registry_user_.default
_registry_machine_security
_registry_machine_software
_registry_machine_system
_registry_machine_sam

D. Create a subdirectory; i.e, D:\Windows\TMP. Copy these files to the TMP subdirectory.  Rename them:

default
security
software
system
sam

*Note*  Be sure to lose the period (.) in the file named _registry_user_.default

E. Delete the files in the D:\windows\system32\config subdirectory with the same names.

F. Copy the D:\windows\tmp files to the D:\windows\system32\config. subdirectory.

G.Put your drive back in its original system.  Your system should start normally.  If you get the same error repeat the procedure and choose another folder ( RPnn) (next highest number). You can repeat this procedure choosing lower RPnn numbers until you get it booting again

If you are denied access to any folders you will have to take "Ownership" of the folders first.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421